# Teach me how to modify and delete from QnA board

Tags: python, django-views, django-templates

I made the buttons '수정' as edit and '삭제' as delete.
But, if I click the button, 404 error came up and I have no idea how to connect the urls.

Here are views.py

```
def question_modify(request, question_id):
    userid = request.session["user"] 
    writer = Member.objects.get(memberID = memberID)
    contents = Question.objects.get(id=question_id)    
    answer_list = Answer.objects.filter(questionID_id=question_id).order_by('-create_dttm')
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    if userid != writer:
        messages.error(request, '수정권한 없습니다.')
        return redirect('qna:detail', question_id=question.id)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = QuestionForm(request.POST, instance=question)
        if form.is_valid():
            question=form.save(commit=False)
            question.modify_date=timezone.now()
            question.save()
            return redirect('qna/detail', question_id=question.id)
    else:
        form=QuestionForm(instance=question)
    context={'contents':contents}
    return render(request, 'qna/question_detail.html', context)
```

And here are urls.py
app_name = 'qna'

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('list/', views.question_list),
    path('write/', views.question_write),
    path('detail/<int:question_id>/', views.question_detail, name='question_detail'),
    path('answer_write/<int:question_id>/', views.answer_write, name='answer_write'),
    path('question/modify/<int:question_id>/', views.question_modify, name='question_modify'),
]
```

These are part of html template which I made the buttons.

```
<div class="col text-end">
{% if memberID == userid %}
     <a href="/qna/modify/{{question.id}}" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">수정</a>
     <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="delete btn btn-outline-secondary" data-        uri="/qna/delete/{{question.id}}">삭제</a>
{% endif %}
</div>
```

The current path, qna/modify/, didn’t match any of these.
어떻게 해야 할지 전혀 감이 안오는데 제발 도와주세요.
함수 상의 문제는 아닌거 같은데 어디서 잘못 된 걸까요..?
도움이 간절히 필요합니다.
[I followed this website to reach the solutions but it doesn't work well. It is mostly about Korean but could you please help me..?](https://wikidocs.net/71445)
I think if I click the button, the url link should lead the page to /qna/modify/question_id. But it just goes to /qna/modify. Why does this problems is happening?
The error code is "Page not found(404)
In urls.py, I indicated that the button should lead to /qna/modify/question_id.. I have no idea how can I fix this problem..
I am stuck with this problem for a week.. Please give me an answer..